# loading shared native modules from ear file than from web apps in JBoss environment

Tags: jboss, native

There is a jar which loads native libraries .so files. This jar is available as a jboss module on the server. Native files can be loaded only once per classloader.
There are two war modules war1, war2 inside an ear1 file. if the module is configured as jboss module in both war1 & war2, I have no issues. But I am looking for an alternative where if i configure the jar which is loading the native library in the earfile/lib and the war refers from there, does that work. That particular class should load only once and shoudl be available in both the war files.

- Solution:

We need to add sub-deployment section to the jboss deployment xml file inside ear/Meta-INF folder. That way the jboss module can be made available to all other submodules/war modules.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.aexp.sec.crypto" export="TRUE" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="crypto-war1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.aexp.sec.crypto" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="crypto-war2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.aexp.sec.crypto" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Can you add code to this?

Comment: Thanks. I got it  worked. I would need to add

Comment: I added your solution below, you can edit if required or you can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: For the Benefits of the future users, adding the solution of @Vamshidhar Cheburthy below,

We need to add sub-deployment section to the JBoss deployment XML file inside ear/Meta-INF folder. That way the JBoss module can be made available to all other submodules/war modules.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.aexp.sec.crypto" export="TRUE" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
<sub-deployment name="crypto-war1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.aexp.sec.crypto" />
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
<sub-deployment name="crypto-war2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.aexp.sec.crypto" />
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
```